# extract unique value and storing with index key

Tags: r, data-science

How can I extract the unique value and its count and store in data frame with index key, in the R language? 
Please help .

any help would be grateful .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: its a CSV data format

Answer (score 0):

You could have done a better job answering the question, for example by providing your data, etc.

Anyways, with what you have said, I think you can use `table()`